# How to manipulate the no result message in filter search jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I have created a filter search field to filter out brand names on a brand page. Now I am stuck at how to show the "No result message" when all  elements display none. And when the typed-in letters in input field are removed one by one, result will be shown up if there are matched letter (no result message will still be shown up if there are still no matched result), until the input value is empty (null?), then the whole brand list shows up again.

```js
// filter field
   $("input#searchTerm").on("keyup", function(){
         var inputValue = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
         if(inputValue)
         $("nav.link-list").each(function(){
              var brand =  $(this).children("a").attr("title");
              $(this).filter(function(){
                 if (brand.toLowerCase().indexOf(inputValue) > -1) {
                     $(this).fadeIn(800);
                } else {
                     $(this).fadeOut(300);
                   
                }
               if($("nav.link-list:visible").length === 0) {
                  $(".page-content").append("<p>Sorry, no matched result is found, please try again.</p>");
               }
         }); // end of .filter()
          
     }); // end of .each()

  }); // end of .on(keyup)
```

```css
.page-content__body {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
.search {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative
}
.searchTerm {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
  outline: none;
  color: #9DBFAF;
  height: 28px !important;
  border: none !important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea !important;
  padding: 0 4px !important;
}

.searchTerm:focus{
  color: #00B4CC;
}

.searchButton {
  position: absolute;  
  right: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: transparent;
  background: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  color: #8e8e8e;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
 margin-top: 4px !important;
}

/*Resize the wrap to see the search bar change!*/
.brand-search-wrap{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-content">
  <h1>Brands</h1>
  <div class="page-content__body">
  
  <div class="brand-search-wrap">
   <div class="search">
      <input type="text" class="searchTerm" id="searchTerm" placeholder="Enter the brand name here">
      <button type="submit" class="searchButton">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
      </button>
   </div>
</div></div>
</div>
<article class="category-list">
    <nav class="link-list">
      <a href="/brands/abus" title="ABUS">ABUS</a>
    </nav>
    <nav class="link-list">
      <a href="/brands/abus" title="ACC">ACC</a>
    </nav>
    <nav class="link-list">
      <a href="/brands/abus" title="BUS">BUS</a>
    </nav>
    <nav class="link-list">
      <a href="/brands/abus" title="BKUS">BKUS</a>
    </nav>
    <nav class="link-list">
      <a href="/brands/abus" title="KUS">KUS</a>
    </nav>
    <nav class="link-list">
      <a href="/brands/abus" title="SUK">SUK</a>
    </nav>
  </article>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   <div class="page-content">
    <h1>Brands</h1>
    <div class="page-content__body">

   <div class="brand-search-wrap">
    <div class="search">
  <input type="text" class="searchTerm" id="searchTerm" placeholder="Enter the brand name here">
    <button type="submit" class="searchButton">
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </button>
    </div> 
    </div></div>
   </div>
    <article class="category-list">


    <p id="no_result_found"></p>


      <nav class="link-list">
     <a href="/brands/abus" title="ABUS">ABUS</a>
    </nav>
   <nav class="link-list">
    <a href="/brands/abus" title="ACC">ACC</a>
    </nav>
     <nav class="link-list">
      <a href="/brands/abus" title="BUS">BUS</a>
      </nav>
     <nav class="link-list">
     <a href="/brands/abus" title="BKUS">BKUS</a>
    </nav>
     <nav class="link-list">
     <a href="/brands/abus" title="KUS">KUS</a>
      </nav>
      <nav class="link-list">
      <a href="/brands/abus" title="SUK">SUK</a>
     </nav>
      </article>


 // filter field
    $("input#searchTerm").on("keyup", function(){
      var inputValue = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
      var checkEmpty = [];

        $(".category-list nav").each(function(){
            var brand =  $(this).find("a").attr("title").toLowerCase();
            if(brand.indexOf(inputValue) > -1) 
            {
              checkEmpty.push('1');
              $(this).fadeIn(800);
            } 
            else 
            {
              $(this).fadeOut(300);   
            }
        }); // end of .each()

        if(checkEmpty.length == 0)
        {
          $('#no_result_found').html('No result found');
        }
        else
        {
          $('#no_result_found').html('');
        }
    }); // end of .on(keyup
```

Answer (score 0):

I think after fadein/fadeout successfully you need to handle that

```
    // filter field
   $("input#searchTerm").on("keyup", function(){
         var inputValue = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
         if(inputValue)
         $("nav.link-list").each(function(){
              var brand =  $(this).children("a").attr("title");
              $(this).filter(function(){
                 if (brand.toLowerCase().indexOf(inputValue) > -1) {
                     $(this).fadeIn(800);
                } else {
                     $(this).fadeOut(300,function(){
    if($("nav.link-list:visible").length === 0) {
                  $(".page-content").append("<p>Sorry, no matched result is found, please try again.</p>");
               }
    });

                }

         }); // end of .filter()

     }); // end of .each()

  }); // end of .on(keyup)
```

Comment: It got problem when I remove the letter in input: the no result message shows up even when there are matched result showing below.